# Is there any tools that will let me check String length of XML Node

Tags: bash, grep, xml, xmllint

Am wondering if there are any tools that will do this:

Exmaple XML:

```
<node1>
 <Data>
 <Unique>123456789-1234567891</Unique> 
 </Data>
</node1>
```

What i was hoping to search was where Unique is Less than 10 left to - 
And if Right is less than 9 from - to right.

So the search would flag this record/node as a problem

```
<Unique>6789-1234567891</Unique>
```

I was trying to use Grep to do this, but there have been various XML tools i have started using in Bash, so i thought i would ask the question first on a specific tool maybe.

xmllint was one i was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry to spam you) Using a XML parser in perl

(if ncessary: `sudo cpan XML::DT`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DT;
my $file = shift;

# $c - contents after child processing

print dt(
   $file,
   'Unique' => sub{$c =~ s/^(\d{1,9}-\d+|\d+-\d{1,8})$/FIXME:$1/; toxml },
)
```

In this case you get a XML anotated with "FIXME"s

Comment: Perfect thanks, Both answers are great, I like the one liner with Grep as i can quickly Stack / Pipe that with other searches. At least i know how to to less = > on the string now. thanks

XML::DT also seems to be a nice way to achieve these results but with more features :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -nP "<Unique>(\d{1,9}-\d+|\d+-\d{1,8})</Unique>" ex.xml`

- `-n` to output the line number of the wrong Uniques